# Poisson equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=y(1-y)(3\sin x - \sin3x)$ on a rectangle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I have been given the problem:

> $$ \begin{cases}
> u_{xx}+u_{yy}=y(1-y)(3\sin x - \sin3x) & 0<x<\pi,0<y<1 & \\ 
> u(x,0)=0 & 0<x<\pi & (1) \\
> u(x,1)=0 & 0<x<\pi & (2) \\
> u(0,y)=u(\pi,y)=0 & 0<y<1 & (3) 
> \end{cases} $$

I have not solved any problem with this type of condition. Every problem I have seen has the condition (1) along with a condition $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ (Initial value problem), combined with (3)  (A certain type of boundary conditions). I don't know how to proceed. Is separation of variables the only way?

Comment: I don't really know how to make sense of this. Shouldn't $u$ have three arguments? In which case, how is this a one dimensional equation? It seems there are two spatial variables.

Comment: In the $x,t$ plane? Then why do you have $u_{yy}$? And then, $t$ doesn't appear in any of the arguments or inequalities! This would make sense as a Poisson equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = \cdots$ in the plane though.

Comment: Oh, and that isn't a wave equation by the way.

Comment: @GPerez My bad, $u_{tt}$ is a typo. Corrected. The equation is given in the xy plane.

Answer (score 0):

Let's represent $u$ by its Fourier series
$$
u(x,y)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}\sin(mx)\sin(n\pi y). \tag{1}
$$
(Because of the boundary conditions, there are no cosine terms in the series.) Plugging $(1)$ into the PDE, we obtain
$$
-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}(m^2+n^2\pi^2)\sin(mx)\sin(n\pi y)=
y(1-y)(3\sin x-\sin 3x). \tag{2}
$$
The coefficients $a_{mn}$ are given by
\begin{align}
a_{mn}&=-\frac{1}{m^2+n^2\pi^2}\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi}y(1-y)(3\sin x-\sin 3x)\sin(mx)\sin(n\pi y)\,dxdy \\
&=-\frac{4}{m^2+n^2\pi^2}\,(3\delta_{m,1}-\delta_{m,3})\,\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3\pi^3}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Substituting $(3)$ in $(1)$ we find
$$
u(x,y)=3f_1(y)\sin x-f_3(y)\sin 3x, \tag{4}
$$
where
$$
f_m(y)=-\frac{4}{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n^3(m^2+n^2\pi^2)}\,\sin(n\pi y)\qquad(m=1,3). \tag{5} \\
$$

---

Equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ give the solution to the problem, but we can go further. Let's show how to find a closed form expression for $f_m$. Since the PDE is linear, we can write its solution as $u=v+w$, where $v$ and $w$ satisfy the PDEs
\begin{align}
&v_{xx}+v_{yy}=3y(1-y)\sin x,\tag{6a} \\
&w_{xx}+w_{yy}=-y(1-y)\sin 3x. \tag{6b}
\end{align}
Substituting $v(x,y)=3f_1(y)\sin x$ in $(6\text{a})$, we verify that $f_1$ satisfies the ODE
$$
f_1''-f_1=y(1-y). \tag{7}
$$
Using the method of undetermined coefficients, we can find a particular solution to $(7)$ of the form $f_{1p}(y)=ay^2+by+c$:
$$
2a-ay^2-by-c=y-y^2 \implies (a,b,c)=(1,-1,2). \tag{8}
$$
Adding $f_{1p}(y)$ to the solution to the homogeneous equation, $f_{1h}(y)=C_1\cosh y + C_2\sinh y$, and applying the boundary conditions $f_1(0)=f_1(1)=0$ to determine the coefficients $C_1, C_2$, we finally obtain
$$
f_1(y)=y^2-y+2(1-\cosh y) +\frac{2(\cosh 1 - 1)}{\sinh 1}\,\sinh y. \tag{9}
$$
In a similar fashion, substituting $w(x,y)=-f_3(y)\sin 3x$ in $(6\text{b})$, we verify that $f_3$ satisfies the ODE
$$
f_3''-9f_3=y(1-y), \tag{10}
$$
whose solution satisfying $f_3(0)=f_3(1)=0$ is
$$
f_3(y)=\frac{1}{9}(y^2-y)+\frac{2}{81}(1-\cosh 3y)
+\frac{2(\cosh 3 - 1)}{81\sinh 3}\,\sinh 3y. \tag{11}
$$
The combination of $(4)$, $(9)$ and $(11)$ gives us the desired solution.